# bind c-w c-w in tmux

Tags: tmux

I want to bind C-w C-w in tmux to `select pane -l`. I basically want the same keybinding in tmux as the one in vim with `C-w C-w`.
I've tried binding `C-w-w`, `C-ww`, `C-w-C-w` but tmux keeps complaining about not knowing the keys so I'm wondering how to map that.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25315824/10765659), but see other answers there for some ideas.

Comment: yeah. it only supports single key plus a mod. i ended using the custom tables to get what i wanted. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a couple of years later but here it is. we have to use a key `table` to do this:

```
bind-key -Ttable1 'C-w' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w' 'select-pane -l'
bind-key -Troot 'C-w' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-w' 'switch-client -Ttable1'
```

in my case I was trying to make it work for vim-tmux. The above is what I have in my `.tmux.conf`.

We are essentially creating a new key table and setting `C-w` as the prefix key for that table and the second `C-w` is a key binding specific to that table that we just created to do what we want.